# WordPress: move enqueued styling from footer to header

Tags: wordpress

I'm using various template parts that use specific styling. To keep the amount of unused styling to a minimum, I've registered the stylesheets in the functions.php and enqueue them on the relevant template parts.

The side effect of this is that the template-part stylesheets are enqueued in the footer. Is there a way to move them to the header?

Comment: Can you provide us the php code you used to enqueue the scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is because by the time your template code runs, the header of the page has always been generated.

I would probably use something like [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) to sniff out which template is being included, and *then* queue the correct style file accordingly...

```
function queue_template_style($template) {
    switch($template) {
        case 'template-1':
            wp_enqueue_style(...);
        break;
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'queue_template_style', 100 );
```

Hope this helps!